# How to create a pipeline to publish a jar file to sharepoint?

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need help with Azure DevOps.

I'm trying to build a pipeline to drop my jar file to SharePoint.

I have created all the repos, but I do not know how to build a pipeline that will drop my jar file to sharepoint.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try uploading the file to the SharePoint using this extension **SharePoint Files Uploader** from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=projectumapsvsts.upload-sp-files-app&ssr=false#overview).

This extension enables you to upload a single file or the contents of a folder (including sub folders) to a SharePoint document library.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Deprecated :/ : `This extension is now unpublished from Marketplace. You can choose to uninstall it.`